# How to combine dict elements in list while changing nested json contents?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

What I have at the moment:

```
list1 = [{"nested_json_a": "nested_values_a"}, {"nested_json_b": "nested_values_b"}, {"nested_json_c": "nested_values_c"}, {"nested_json_d": "nested_values_d"}]
```

What I want to do is essentially combine `nested_json_a` and `nested_json_c` together as well as `nested_json_b` and `nested_json_d`. The catch here is that in the end there only needs to be two elements in the entire list with the output looking something like as follows:

```
list1 = [
   {
      "combined_a_c":{
         "nested_json_a":"nested_values_a",
         "nested_json_c":"nested_values_c"
   },
      "combined_b_d":{
         "nested_json_b":"nested_values_b",
         "nested_json_d":"nested_values_d"
      }
   }
]
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this? Been stuck and struggling with this for a while now.

Comment: your output is not valid JSON or valid list of dicts

Comment: Is it correct now? Does what I'm trying to say not make sense? Essentially I'm trying to combine the a and c list elements together along with b and d, while nesting the contents in one JSON with a new combined overarching name

Comment: Read the json file, perform changes in python, overwrite the whole json file.

Comment: I'm not too picky about the JSON format honestly as long as the basic combined information idea is there

Comment: @KennyOstrom but how would I perform the changes in python is my question. I'm planning on automating this portion so can't do this manually

Comment: dict has an update method which might be helpful. I don't want to say too much more. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update

Comment: it's the same, still not valid one

Comment: @buran why is it invalid?

Comment: @buran why do you think it's invalid?

Comment: Hey @RicardoFrancois, did I get it right that as a result you'd like to have a dict with just two elements? One having odd, the other having even elements?

Comment: @NickShebanov yup that's correct, only thing is I also want those elements to be nested together inside a new JSON layer as in my post too

Comment: @DeepSpace, my bad, after OP edited it is OK. They removed some curly braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd
nested = dd(dict)
for d in list1:
    for k in d:
        if k in keys_dict: # you need to decide what to do with a key that doesn't have a combined key to move to
            nested[keys_dict[k]][k]=d[k]
```

this will return a dict of dicts instead a list of dicts

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'combined_a_c': {'nested_json_a': 'nested_values_a', 'nested_json_c': 'nested_values_c'}, 'combined_b_d': {'nested_json_b': 'nested_values_b', 'nested_json_d': 'nested_values_d'}})
```

if its important that it will be a list of dicts, convert it

```
new_list1= []
for k in nested:
    new_list1.append({k:nested[k]})
```